# How to initialize, pass argument, and check error condition using NSError**

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, nserror

`Xcode 4.3`

I've read the SO questions on NSError**, so I wrote a simple test program that uses a slightly different syntax recommended by Xcode 4.3 (see `__autoreleasing` below), so I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, although the code does appear to function properly. Anyway, just a simple file reader, prints an error if the file can't be found.

**Questions**

Would like to know if the NSError initialization, argument passing using `&`, and error condition checking are correct. 
Also, in the `readFileAndSplit..` method, I noticed a big difference between `if(!*error)` and `if(!error)`, in fact, `if(!error)` does not work when no error condition is raised.

**File Reading Method w/Possible Error Condition**

```
 -(NSArray*) readFileAndSplitLinesIntoArray:(NSError *__autoreleasing *) error {
    NSString* rawFileContents =
          [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"props.txt"
                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding    
                                       error:error
    NSArray* fileContentsAsArray = nil;  
    if(!*error)
          fileContentsAsArray = 
                [rawFileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    return fileContentsAsArray;
```

**Caller**

```
SimpleFileReader* reader = ...
NSError* fileError = nil;
NSArray* array = [reader readFileAndSplitLinesIntoArray: &fileError];

if(fileError){
  NSLog(@"Error was : %@, with code: %li", 
       [fileError localizedDescription],(long)[fileError code]);
}
```

Comment: Only thing I'd change is test whether the `rawFileContents` is `nil` rather than the existence of the error. The main return value is supposed to indicate success or failure in Cocoa, and the error is not guaranteed to be absent when methods otherwise succeed, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Ok, good point, but when checking for the error anyway, is `if(!*error)` correct? I found this to work for both error and non-error conditions in the `readFile...` method. I'm dereferencing the double pointer, if it's not null, then something went wrong, I'm assuming that's the correct way to check.

Comment: I would do it just as you are.

Comment: Except Darren is right about the `NULL` check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues.

First, As per [Apple's Error Handling Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html), you should be checking a method's return value to determine whether a method failed or not, and not NSError.  You only use NSError to get additional error information in the event that the method failed.

E.g.:

```
NSArray* fileContentsAsArray = nil;
NSString* rawFileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"props.txt"
                                encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding    
                                   error:error];
if (rawFileContents)
{
    // Method succeeded
    fileContentsAsArray = [rawFileContents ...];
}

return fileContentsAsArray; // may be nil
```

Second, NSError out parameters are typically optional and may be NULL.  But if you pass a NULL error variable into your method it will crash on this line:

```
if (!*error) {
```

because you're dereferencing a NULL pointer.  Instead, you must always check for NULL before referencing a pointer, like so:

```
if (error && *error) 
{
    // Do something with the error info
}
```

However, if you rewrite the method as indicated above then you won't be accessing the error variable at all.

Comment: Makes sense, but confused about one thing. In the caller, I initialized `NSError fileError = nil` and passed that to `readFile...` as `&fileError` but irrespective of the file loading or not, `if(!*error)` never raises BAD ACCESS, it always works as expected...am I missing something?

Comment: You're passing a pointer to your fileError variable, and that pointer is always non-null (regardless of the value of fileError).  Instead, try passing in no variable, e.g. `[reader readFileAndSplitLinesIntoArray:NULL]`

Comment: good point (pun intended), damn pointers are tricky, thanks for the info